# Gusser Game not reloading the page, after GameOver

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to javascript and I was trying to build a small guesser game app; however, every thing is Ok except for reloading the page after the game is over, the page is not reloading when clicking 'Play Again' and the button end up just disabled.

Please help me with this issue, I can not figure it out on my own.

```
let min = 1, max = 10, winnerNum = RandNum(max,min), gussNum = 3;

// UI vars

let game = document.querySelector('#game'),
    minNum = document.querySelector('.min-num'),
    maxNum = document.querySelector('.max-num'),
    gussBtn = document.querySelector('#gussBtn'),
    gussInput = document.querySelector('#input'),
    message = document.querySelector('.msg');

// assign min and max

minNum.textContent = min;
maxNum.textContent = max;

// reload the game

game.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){
    if(e.target.className ==='play-again'){
        window.location.reload();
        // Why is the page is not reloaded ??
    }
});

// listent to the gussed number

gussBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let guss = parseInt(gussInput.value);
    console.log(guss);

    //validate

    if(guss===winnerNum){
        gameOver(true,`Winner Winner Chicken Dinner, Yes ${winnerNum} is the correct number`)
    } else{
        gussNum -= 1;

        if(gussNum===0){
            gameOver(false,`You lost game over, the correct number is ${winnerNum}`)
        } else if(gussNum<0){
            gussBtn.disabled=true;
            gussInput.disabled=true;
        } else {
            gussInput.disabled=true;
            gussInput.style.borderColor = 'red';
            gussInput.value = '';
            setMessage(`You have ${gussNum} left!`, 'red')
        }
    }
});

function gameOver(won,msg){
    let color;
    won === true ? color = 'green' : color='red';
    gussInput.disabled=true;
    gussInput.style.borderColor = color;
    // gussBtn.disabled=true;
    setMessage(msg, color);
    gussBtn.value='Play Again';
    gussBtn.classList.add('play-again');

}

function RandNum(max,min) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*(max-min+1)-min);
}


function setMessage(msg, color) {
    message.textContent = msg;
    message.style.color = color;
}
```

HTML

```
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
        <div class="card card-body text-center mt-5">
            <h1 class="heading display-5 pb-3">Game Gusser</h1>
            <p>Guess a number between <span class="min-num"></span> and <span class="max-num"></span></p>
                <div class="form-group" id="game">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="input" placeholder="Enter your guess...">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-dark btn-block mt-4" id="gussBtn">
                    </div>
                    <p class="msg mt-4"></p>
                </div>
        </div>            
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

I want when clicking Play Again btn the page reloads and user can play it again.

Comment: Please add your `HTML` code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible that the className is not exactly 'play-again'. 
Also why not simply 'click' event?

```
function hasClass ( elem , klass ) {
    return (" " + elem.className + " " ).indexOf( " " + klass + " " ) > -1
}; 

let game = document.getElementById('game');
game.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    if (hasClass(e.target , 'play-again')){
        window.location.reload();
    }
});
```

Would also recommend against using location.reload(). Extremely bad user experience. Why not simply re-run the script that initializes the game in the first place?

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
1- 'click' reloads the page without displaying the changed value of the submit button directly, I want the button submit value to change to Play Again then when I click it the page reloads.
2- 'play-again' is correctly written, I double checked to make sure there is not typo.
3- I liked your code solution, but I would appreciate it if you could help me understand whats wrong with my code.
Thank you again

Comment: Theraot, 1. it will not return true for 'play-again-fake' as it wraps the given 'klass' in spaces. 2. Contains is a more modern solution and has lesser support than indexOf - in terms of performance, it is extremely neglijable at best, at this state. 3.He was using classList and checking if it matched the 'play-again' string exactly. He has also updated his code **after** my post was made.

Comment: Thank you both Andru and Theraot, I got it now you taught me something today :)